# Linux - Disabing buffered I/O to file in the child processes

Tags: linux, buffering

In my application I am creating a bunch of child processes. After fork() I open a per process file, set the stdout/stderr of the created process to point to that file and then exec the intended program.

Is there an option for the parent process to setup things such a way that when the child process does a printf it gets flushed immediately to the output file without having to call flush() ? Or is there an API that can be called from the child process itself (before exec) to disable buffered I/O ?

Comment: See the man page for setvbuf, you can set stdout to unbuffered. stderr is already set to unbuffered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `printf` is buffered.  The underlying file descriptors are not buffered in that way (they are buffered in the kernel, but the other end can read from the same kernel buffer).  You can change the buffering using `setvbuf` as mentioned in a comment which should have been an answer.

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

You do not need to do this for `stdin` or `stderr`.

You can't do this from the parent process.  This is because the buffers are created by the child process.  The parent process can only manipulate the underlying file descriptors (which are in the kernel), not `stdout` (which is part of the C library).

**P.S.** You mean `fflush`, not `flush`.

Comment: This answer is mostly correct. Except for the "buffered in the kernel." stdio facility, `printf()` and `setvbuf()` are parts of, is buffered in the libc. Buffered in kernel are the pipes and fifos, but the question explicitly states that the redirection to files takes place. IOW, if the child process can be modified, then the supplied call to `setvbuf()` on stdout should be added at the beginning of the main of the child process. (stderr is by default not buffered.)

Comment: @Dummy00001: All IO is buffered in the kernel, unless you use some extension like `O_DIRECT`, in which case it will still be buffered by the disk before it is written.

Comment: Looks like the setvbuf() is not retained across an exec ? I have something like this..      if (fork() == 0) {    <open a temp file and redirect stdout/err to this file>    setvbuf()    exec() }  printf calls in the execed code are still getting buffered..

Comment: That is right.  `setvbuf` is not retained across an exec, which is why I said you can't do it from the parent process.  I guess I could have made that more clear...  Do you understand the difference between a file descriptor and a `FILE`?  Perhaps you could read up on that...